# joomla 2.5, user authentication

Tags: authentication, joomla

I am currently trying to work out a solution, how to make an authentication for my Joomla 2.5 website.
   I did the log in form, and created test users, although I don't know how to access Joomla DB. Can you help me find a solution for my question. The answers I found on google, I didn't quite understand.
   It would be really nice if someone would share some good tutorials.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , I think it will be useful to you,
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 1):

Joomla manages authentication for you via its user management and authentication system. It already provides you with a login form in fact ... but more importantly it provides you with authentication and user plugins that you can add your own to if you need something different.  This is the point of using a CMS to have a platform that already provides you with secure and well tested user  management among other thigns.